# Decode Encoded Html Source

Tags: python, html, encode, meta-tags

I have considered the source of a page in linked_in, and I found the source code is like the following (part of the source is copied). I want to know, how this sources are encoded and how can I decode them (as an example). Most of the data is encoded in some meta tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">!function(i,n){void 0!==i.addEventListener&&void 0!==i.hidden&&(n.liVisibilityChangeListener=function(){i.hidden&&(n.liHasWindowHidden=!0)},i.addEventListener("visibilitychange",n.liVisibilityChangeListener))}(document,window);</script>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>LinkedIn</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#0077B5">

<meta name="extended/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22extended%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22production%22%2C%22lix%22%3A%7B%22tests%22%3A%5B%22voyager.feed.web.native-video-hls%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.enable-su-sequence-number%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.article-mini-tags%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.likes-comments-fetch-override-to-zero%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.enable-edited-comment-flag%22%2C%22publishin%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.sharing.twitter-visibility%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.sharing.upload-image-as-media-proxy%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.sharing.show-original-author-context%22%2C%22voyager.feed.client.hashtags%22%2C%22voyager.feed.client.flex-height-image%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.postsVertical%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.right-rail-news-module%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.rich-media.hide-reshare-button%22%2C%22voyager.web.feed.right-rail.follow-recommendations%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.right-rail.follow-recommendations-recent-shares%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.incorrectly-mentioned-in-news-update-action%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.follow-nav-following-count%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.follow-nav-followers-count%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.network-follow-updates%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.topic-recommendations%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.followers-page%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.follow-fpr-page%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.unfollow-channel-action%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.auto-play.v2%22%2C%22voyager.feed.video.autoplay.support%22%2C%22voyager.feed.video.autoplay.ugc%22%2C%22voyager.feed.video.isTwitterDisabled%22%2C%22voyager.publishing.web.video.player-beacon%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.video-upload%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.video-upload.duration-limit%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.video-frosted-background%22%2C%22voyager.sharing.web.allow-disable-comments%22%2C%22voyager.web.feed.incremental-update%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.increment-sponsored-sequence%22%2C%22voyager.sharing.web.mentions%22%2C%22voyager.sharing.web.mentions.api%22%2C%22voyager.sharing.web.remember-visibility-settings%22%2C%22voyager.sharing.web.cache-visibility-settings%22%2C%22voyager.web.feed.fie.visibleHeight%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.cached-feed-data%22%2C%22voyager.web.feed.perf.layered-rendering%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.batch-right-rail-adjustments%22%2C%22learning.rec.daily-bites-campaign.flagship%22%2C%22voyager.web.feed.right-rail.learning-bites%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.right-rail-learning-bites-above-ad%22%2C%22voyager.web.feed.enableGaPixelCall%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.premium-top-applicant-jobs%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.su-csp%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.premium-learning-course-autoplay%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.identity-module-premium-access%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.identity-module-premium-branding-entitlement-change%22%2C%22voyager.common.web.entity-hovercards%22%2C%22lego_jobs_open_candidates_banner_widget%22%2C%22neptune.jobs.enableInitiateReferrals%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.jobDetails.premium.upsells.rightrail.variation%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.careers-dashboard-pill-count%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.enable-jobs-home-jymbii-pojo%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.enabledActionableSkillPills%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.enableGaPixelCall%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.extended.open-candidate-enable%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.extended.open-candidate-title-version%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.job-basic-quality-match%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.job-detail-links%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.job-match-message-card%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.jobs-details-salary%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.jobs-home-search-starters%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.jobs-home-track%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.jymbii-browsemap%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.marketing-banner%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-fast-growing-companies-learning-upsell%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-link-to-companies-page%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-salary-histogram%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-show-premium-flavors-jserp%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-top-applicant-jobs-carousel%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-top-applicant-jobs-learning-upsell%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.profinder-jobs-home-promo%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.recent-resumes%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.work-authorization%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.jobs-fast-growing-companies-typeahead%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.jobs-fastGrowingCompaniesUpsell%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.jobs-hide-top-applicant-locations%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.jobs-insight-fast-growing-companies%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.jobs-make-skills-available-for-freemembers%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.jobs-top-applicant-upsell%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.lazy-load-jymbii-for-premium%22%2C%22neptune.jobs.enabledPremiumFeedback%22%2C%22neptune.jobs.enableInitiateReferrals%22%2C%22neptune.jobs.enableSalaryLink%22%2C%22neptune.jobs.premium.enabledCombinedJobsNullState%22%2C%22voyager.jobs-search.web.jobs-save-jobs%22%2C%22voyager.jobs-search.web.jobs-search-box%22%2C%22voyager.jobs-search.web.prefetch-next-page%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.badge-promo-link%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.enableP4pHovercard%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.enableP4pUpsell%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.enableProfinderJobDetailCard%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.extended.open-candidate-enable%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.extended.open-candidate-title-version%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.jobs-details-salary%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-course-recommendations-jobs-details%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-course-recommendations-jobs-details-headline%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-course-recommendations-jobs-details-placement%22%2C%22voyager.jobs.web.premium-top-applicant-jobs-carousel%22%2C%22voyager.l2m.web.extended.app-download-promo-jobs%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.jobs-fast-growing-companies-typeahead%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.extended.left-rail%22%2C%22voyager.jobs-search.web.disable-truncate-job-title%22%2C%22voyager.jobs-search.web.jymbii-on-no-results-page%22%2C%22voyager.jobs-search.web.prefetch-jobs-search-in-jobs%22%2C%22voyager.search.jobs-search.web.redirect-to-jserp%22%2C%22voyager.jobs-search.web.facets-on-top%22%2C%22neptune.launchpad.collapse-cool-off%22%2C%22neptune.launchpad.toggle-button-text%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.lead-capture-custom-insight-threshold%22%2C%22voyager.me-ca.web.header-tabs%22%2C%22voyager.me.web.get_introduced_cta%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence-bootstrap-max-batch-size%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence-subscription-max-size%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence-ui%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.truncate-legal-text%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.inmail-expiration%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.expiring-inmail-days%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.ember-data-upgrade%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-performant-loading-spinner%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-conversation-initial-render-count%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-markallseen-client-call%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-messagelist-raf%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-mailboxcount%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-events%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-conversations%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-settings%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-occluded-conversation-cards%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.enable-spinmail-cta-designs%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.enable-inline-inmail-quick-replies%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.load-convo-history-on-pillar-compose%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-quick-replies%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-realtime-onboarding%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-inmail-reply-deeplinking%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-premium-sub-inmail-quick-replies%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-enable-inmail%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-inmail-convo-bubble-size%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.hiring-manager-mailbox%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant-entry-points%22%2C%22neptune.messaging.overlay%22%2C%22neptune.messaging.overlay.open-list-by-default%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant-entry-points%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-contextual%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-defer-data-fetch%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-disable-reload-on-reconnect%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-load-latest-conversation-on-compose%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-convo-save-minimize-state%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-list-save-minimize-state%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-list-badging%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-fetch-events-on-hover%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-connection-search%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence-bootstrap-max-batch-size%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence-subscription-max-size%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.presence-ui%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.truncate-legal-text%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.inmail-expiration%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.client.expiring-inmail-days%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.ember-data-upgrade%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-performant-loading-spinner%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-conversation-initial-render-count%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-markallseen-client-call%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-messagelist-raf%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-mailboxcount%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-events%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-conversations%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-nonblocking-settings%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.bertie-occluded-conversation-cards%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.enable-spinmail-cta-designs%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.core.enable-inline-inmail-quick-replies%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.load-convo-history-on-pillar-compose%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-quick-replies%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-realtime-onboarding%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-inmail-reply-deeplinking%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.enable-premium-sub-inmail-quick-replies%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-enable-inmail%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-inmail-convo-bubble-size%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.hiring-manager-mailbox%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant-entry-points%22%2C%22neptune.messaging.overlay%22%2C%22neptune.messaging.overlay.open-list-by-default%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.linkedin-assistant-entry-points%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-contextual%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-defer-data-fetch%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-disable-reload-on-reconnect%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-load-latest-conversation-on-compose%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-convo-save-minimize-state%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-list-save-minimize-state%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-list-badging%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-fetch-events-on-hover%22%2C%22voyager.messaging.web.extended.overlay-connection-search%22%2C%22desktop.abi.flip.m2m.m2g%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi.m2g.results.cta%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi.m2m.results.cta%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi.results.minimalDesign%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi.results.noDeselectCounter%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi.show-referrals-campaign%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi-m2g-results-show-referrals-campaign%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi-results-redirect-to-import%22%2C%22voyager.web.mynetwork.abi.paginated.results%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.pymk-hero%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.load-contextual-pymk-on-connect%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.invitation-action-fail-error%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.appactivation.restriction%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.relevant-invitations%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.appactivation.restriction.variant%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.cache-prefetch-500m-force-visible-true%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.perf-person-info-card-index%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.paginated-invitation-manager%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.gymk-tracking%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.app-activation-get-app-overlay-variant%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.force-clear-badge%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.new-heathrow-redirect-send%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.new-heathrow-redirect-accept%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.new-heathrow-redirect-accept-email%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.customize-after-invite-send%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.show-connected-timestamp%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.use-list-for-elements%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.perf-invite-sent-less-pymk%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.connection-suggester%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.abi.iwe.custom.message%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.abiPromoInMiddleRail%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.contactSyncing%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.wyloPromoInLeftRail%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.wylo-promo.copy%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.wylo-promo.cta%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.wylo-promo.icon%22%2C%22voyager.web.mynetwork.abi.paginated.results%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.abi.results.minimalDesign%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.abi-promo-right-rail%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.abi-results-cta-style%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.perf-nonblocking-model-pymk%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.right-rail-background%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.remove-abi-ads%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.show-german-email-logos%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.abi-cta-variant%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.perf-layered-rendering-invite-sent%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.paginated-invitation-manager%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.show-pymk-dismiss-btn-on-hover%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.abi-results-show-success-step%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.abi-results-cta-style%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.extended.im-parallel-request%22%2C%22voyager.notifications.web.settings-option-model%22%2C%22voyager.me.web.notifications.project-virality%22%2C%22voyager.notifications.web.show-unfollow-setting-option%22%2C%22voyager.notifications.web.show-delete-setting-option%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.marketplace-mentorship%22%2C%22voyager.profile.client.marketplace-member-category%22%2C%22org.media.library%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.school-targeting%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.mount-organization-admin-engine%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.company-admin-redesign%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.enable-copy-link%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.request-admin%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.overview-redesign%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.server-side-recipes%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.lead-capture-custom-insight-threshold%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.top-ranked-companies-badge%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.overview-stock-quote%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-alumni%22%2C%22org.premium.company.insights.upsell.copy%22%2C%22org.premium.company.insights.upsell.placement%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-freemium%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.insights-freemium-copy%22%2C%22voyager.organization.api.premium-insights-unlock-company-gate%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-peers-headcount%22%2C%22voyager.organization.api.premium-headcount-insights-for-jss%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-peers-function%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-freemium-paywall%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-peers-survey-subscriber%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-peers-survey-nonsubscriber%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.welcome-banner-my-premium-entry-point%22%2C%22voyager.premium.api.my-premium-access%22%2C%22premium.mypremium.explore-premium-access%22%2C%22voyager.premium.api.undo-cancel-access%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.my-premium-top-applicant-ranks-fetch%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.my-premium.typeahead%22%2C%22voyager.profile-edit.web.industry-update-from-position-form%22%2C%22voyager.profile-edit.web.allow-webgl%22%2C%22voyager.profile-edit.web.filter-smaller-preset-previews-first%22%2C%22voyager.web.profile.photoOptOut%22%2C%22voyager.web.profile-view.redirectToVanityName%22%2C%22voyager.edit.web.photoFilters%22%2C%22voyager.edit.web.img-edit-button-refactor%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.appactivation.restriction%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.bg-img-v2%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.dashboard-analytics-copy%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.dashboard-card%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.photo-education-tooltip%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.pcm-1.6%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.search-appearances-phase-one%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.use-custom-confirmation-modal%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.marketplace-mentorship%22%2C%22voyager.profile.client.marketplace-member-category%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.topcard-overflow-menu-move%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.semaphore-error-toasts%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.profile-actions-platform%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.extended.sesame-credit%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.extended.wechat%22%2C%22voyager.feed.web.premium-learning-course-autoplay%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.extended.photo-education-tooltip%22%2C%22voyager.profile-ge.web.skill-insight%22%2C%22voyager.profile-ge.web.use-back-for-close%22%2C%22voyager.profile.web.search-appearances-phase-one%22%2C%22neptune.profile.recent-activity.right-rail-ad%22%2C%22neptune.profile.recent-activity.top-text-ad%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-alumni%22%2C%22org.premium.company.insights.upsell.copy%22%2C%22org.premium.company.insights.upsell.placement%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-freemium%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.insights-freemium-copy%22%2C%22voyager.organization.api.premium-insights-unlock-company-gate%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-peers-headcount%22%2C%22voyager.organization.api.premium-headcount-insights-for-jss%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-peers-function%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-insights-freemium-paywall%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-peers-survey-subscriber%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.premium-peers-survey-nonsubscriber%22%2C%22neptune.search.lazy-filters%22%2C%22voyager.search.api.blended-srp%22%2C%22voyager.feed.client.storyline-social-proof%22%2C%22voyager.search.api.people-profile-actions%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.add-connection-of-facet%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.blended-srp%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.chartbeat-analytics%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.hide-headless-profile-actions%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.jymbii-ads%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.news-module-under-sticky-ad%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.no-results-page-v2%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.postsVertical%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.preload-profile-engine%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.premium-facets%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.results-initial-render-count%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.search-ads%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.search-connections%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.search-connections-link-jobs%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.search-tracking-v2%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.srp-right-rail-news-module%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.sort-content-results%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.storyline-core-rail-header%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.typeaheadStaggerChunkSize%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.typeaheadStaggerTime%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.update-count%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.extended.left-rail%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.extended.email-invite%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.extended.lazy-profile-actions%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.extended.premium-upsell-cta-change%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.company-vanity-urls%22%2C%22voyager.web.footer.l2m.app.promo.link%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.app-launcher.unified-acquisition-upsell%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.companies%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.feed%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.jobs%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.jobs%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.messaging%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.mynetwork%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.notifications%22%2C%22voyager.client.perf.cache-prefetch-whitelist.profile%22%2C%22voyager.client.staff%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.contextmenu-cie%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.disable-ghost-content%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.disableMux%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.new-tab-beacon%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.extended.abp-detection%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.heathrow-abi-results-copy%22%2C%22voyager.mynetwork.web.heathrow-feed-copy%22%2C%22voyager.tracking-overlay%22%2C%22cdn_use_cedexis_beacon%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.app-launcher-format%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.app-launcher-label%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.app-launcher.unified-acquisition-upsell%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.extended.loading-bar%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.extended.route-through-heathrow%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.extended.white-bar-underline%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.gold-premium-upsell%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.learning-entry-point%22%2C%22voyager.infra.web.nav.recent-activity-link%22%2C%22voyager.l2m.client.realtime-badging%22%2C%22voyager.premium.api.premium-toggle%22%2C%22voyager.web.has-campaign-manager%22%2C%22voyager.web.nav.low.connection%22%2C%22voyager.web.nav.salary-in-app-launcher%22%2C%22should.audit.comscore.beacon.pemberly%22%2C%22should.audit.nielsen.beacon.pemberly%22%2C%22should.fire.comscore.beacon.pemberly%22%2C%22should.fire.nielsen.beacon.pemberly%22%2C%22voyager.web.component-lazy-render%22%2C%22voyager.organization.web.wvmp-premium-teaser%22%2C%22premium.essentials.launch%22%2C%22voyager.web.custom-add-connections%22%2C%22voyager.premium.web.reactivation-access%22%2C%22voyager.search.web.typeahead-vnext%22%2C%22voyager.sharing.web.guest-public-visibility-dropdown-descriptions%22%2C%22voyager.me.web.my-premium-dropdown%22%2C%22site_speed_v_engagement_trt%22%2C%22site_speed_v_engagement_rep%22%5D%2C%22overrides%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22rootURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22routerRootURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22deviceFormFactor%22%3A%22DESKTOP%22%2C%22enableLixFrontend%22%3Atrue%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22voyager-location%22%2C%22namespace%22%3A%22voyager/api%22%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22locale%22%3A%22en_US%22%2C%22rumConfig%22%3A%7B%22pageKeyPrefix%22%3A%22d_%22%2C%22beacon-service%22%3A%22tracking%22%2C%22beacon-url%22%3A%22/li/track%22%2C%22event-name%22%3A%22RealUserMonitoringEvent%22%2C%22enable-cdn-tracking%22%3Atrue%2C%22enable-pop-tracking%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22name%22%3A%22extended%22%2C%22version%22%3A%22voyager-web_1.0.11509%22%7D%2C%22eyeglass%22%3A%7B%22persistentCache%22%3Afalse%2C%22cssDir%22%3A%22assets%22%2C%22verbose%22%3Atrue%2C%22relativeAssets%22%3Atrue%2C%22sourceFiles%22%3A%5B%22app.scss%22%2C%22critical.scss%22%2C%22se-image-edit.scss%22%2C%22se-search.scss%22%2C%22shared-ext.scss%22%2C%22theme.scss%22%2C%22s-organization.scss%22%2C%22s-salary.scss%22%2C%22se-salary.scss%22%2C%22se-social-share.scss%22%2C%22s-opportunities.scss%22%2C%22se-opportunities.scss%22%2C%22feed-shared-ext.scss%22%2C%22feed-shared-global.scss%22%2C%22feed-global.scss%22%2C%22me-ca-global.scss%22%2C%22me-global.scss%22%2C%22messaging-global.scss%22%2C%22messaging-overlay.scss%22%2C%22mynetwork-global.scss%22%2C%22notifications-global.scss%22%2C%22notifications-shared-ext.scss%22%2C%22notifications-shared-global.scss%22%2C%22onboarding-global.scss%22%2C%22profile-global.scss%22%2C%22profile-subroutes-global.scss%22%2C%22profile-edit-shared.scss%22%2C%22profile-edit-shared-ext.scss%22%2C%22search-global.scss%22%2C%22profile-search-analytics-global.scss%22%2C%22takeover-ext.scss%22%2C%22premium-global.scss%22%2C%22profile-edit-global.scss%22%2C%22opportunities-global.scss%22%2C%22company-creation-global.scss%22%2C%22jobs-global.scss%22%2C%22jobs-shared-global.scss%22%2C%22jobs-shared-ext.scss%22%2C%22profile-ge-global.scss%22%2C%22crosspromo.scss%22%2C%22sharing.scss%22%2C%22sharing-ext.scss%22%2C%22premium-organization.scss%22%2C%22launchpad-ext.scss%22%2C%22se-jobs-jobs-search.scss%22%5D%7D%2C%22browserify%22%3A%7B%22sourcemaps%22%3A%7B%22enabled%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%5C%22none%5C%22%20*.licdn.com%20*.licdn-ei.com%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%5C%22self%5C%22%20%5C%22unsafe-inline%5C%22%20*.licdn.com%20*.licdn-ei.com%20*.linkedin.com%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%5C%22self%5C%22%20*.licdn.com%20*.licdn-ei.com%20*.slidesharecdn.com%22%2C%22frame-src%22%3A%22*.youtube.com%20*.slideshare.net%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%5C%22self%5C%22%20localhost%3A*%20*.linkedin.com%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%5C%22self%5C%22%20*.slidesharecdn.com%20*.licdn.com%20*.licdn-ei.com%20spdy.linkedin.com%20spdy.linkedin-ei.com%20*.youtube.com%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%5C%22self%5C%22%20%5C%22unsafe-inline%5C%22%20*.licdn.com%20*.licdn-ei.com%22%2C%22media-src%22%3A%22%5C%22self%5C%22%20*.slidesharecdn.com%20*.licdn.com%20*.licdn-ei.com%22%7D%2C%22tracking%22%3A%7B%22appId%22%3A%22com.linkedin.flagship3.d_web%22%2C%22pageKeyPrefix%22%3A%22d_%22%2C%22pveTrackingInfo%22%3A%7B%22osName%22%3A%22phone_web%22%7D%2C%22impression%22%3A%7B%22timeThreshold%22%3A300%2C%22percentageThreshold%22%3A50%2C%22viewportOffset%22%3A%7B%22top%22%3A52%2C%22bottom%22%3A0%2C%22left%22%3A0%2C%22right%22%3A0%7D%7D%2C%22comScore%22%3A%7B%22enabled%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%2C%22defaultRootMargin%22%3A%7B%22top%22%3A52%2C%22bottom%22%3A0%2C%22left%22%3A0%2C%22right%22%3A0%7D%2C%22skeleton%22%3A%7B%22data%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22template%22%3A%22./skeleton/loader.hbs%22%7D%2C%22muxr%22%3A%7B%22whitelist%22%3A%7B%22envelope%22%3A%7B%22Accept%22%3Atrue%2C%22Csrf-Token%22%3Atrue%2C%22X-LI-Lang%22%3Atrue%2C%22X-li-page-instance%22%3Atrue%2C%22X-LI-Track%22%3Atrue%2C%22X-RestLi-Protocol-Version%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%2C%22sparkPlaceholders%22%3A%7B%22includeHashes%22%3A%5B%22assets/highcharts/highcharts.js%22%2C%22assets/highcharts/modules/map.js%22%2C%22assets/proj4.js%22%2C%22assets/world.js%22%2C%22assets/src/chartbeat.js%22%2C%22assets/favicon.ico%22%2C%22assets/favicon-notification.ico%22%5D%2C%22splitVendorJs%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22enableEngines%22%3Atrue%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Afalse%2C%22googleAnalytics%22%3A%7B%22trackingId%22%3A%22UA-62256447-1%22%7D%2C%22appVersion%22%3A%221.0.*%22%2C%22logTracking%22%3Afalse%2C%22disableBatching%22%3Afalse%2C%22enableComponentUsageReport%22%3Atrue%2C%22artdeco%22%3A%7B%7D%7D" />
```

I should have mentioned that I can't find any proper keyword to find a proper article about this. Also, any specific solution in python is appreciated.

## Update

The meaning of decoding here, is just not charater decoding. I wanna get the real html soruce which is given in chrome developer tools like the below:

[image]

As you can see, in developer tools, I can see decoded source in a regular html format, but I cannot see that as source of the page (I see what I have mentioned in the first).

Comment: Looks like the same, maybe you can `Ctrl+F` to find the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = ''' your meta content ...'''

from urllib.parse import unquote
unquote(s)
```

---

### urllib.parse.unquote(string, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')

> Replace %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent. The optional
>   encoding and errors parameters specify how to decode percent-encoded
>   sequences into Unicode characters, as accepted by the bytes.decode()
>   method.
>
> string must be a str.
>
> encoding defaults to 'utf-8'. errors defaults to 'replace', meaning
>   invalid sequences are replaced by a placeholder character.
>
> Example: unquote('/El%20Ni%C3%B1o/') yields '/El Niño/'.

Answer (score 0):

**Percent-encoding (or) URL Encoded Data**

> URL encoding stands for encoding certain characters in a URL by replacing them with one or more character triplets that consist of the percent character "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits. The two hexadecimal digits of the triplet(s) represent the numeric value of the replaced character.
>
> The term URL encoding is a bit inexact because the encoding procedure is not limited to URLs (Uniform Resource Locators), but can also be applied to any other URIs (Uniform Resource Identifiers) such as URNs (Uniform Resource Names). Therefore, the term percent-encoding should be preferred.

There are site you can decode the content http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

I'm  note in python but in JavaScript encode/decoding can be done using `encodeURIComponent("DATA_TO_ENCODE")` and  `decodeURIComponent("ENCODED_DATA")`